# How to Locate Call Stack Window in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 (Ultimate Edition)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm currently using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 (Ultimate Edition), and I'm having trouble locating the Call Stack window. When I access the debug window, it appears to be empty. I've attached a screenshot for reference.
I am also attaching the screenshot with the Service window opened.

In your responses, please avoid assuming that I can easily locate icons and instead provide instructions starting from the menu. If you still refer to icons, then a screenshot is appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance.

[image]

[image: Service Window]

Comment: Your debug window is empty because there's no code running in debug mode. Start your app first, then something will appear.

Comment: ... why does this question read like a forwarded email?

Comment: @Jorn It looks like the question was generated by the AI Assistant.

Comment: The screenshot shows you do not have any debug session active. Call stack appears once you start a debug configuration and it's stopped on the breakpoint. You have hints in the debug window how to do it. You can find more details here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html. Does it help?

Comment: No, the debug already started, the code stopped in the breakpoint, I will attach the screenshot of the Service window.  Th text is corrected to avoid using AI help

Comment: With the Services view, you can find it here: https://i.imgur.com/BpHqEor.png. If you don't see it, restore the default layout: https://i.imgur.com/Q9hOG7z.png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You collapsed the **Threads** view. Drag here to expand it back or [restore the layout](https://i.imgur.com/Q9hOG7z.png):

[image: expand here]